# Wordpress how to send email confirmations on post status change

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, wordpress-admin

I have a custom post type called "Booking" in `WP travel` plugin. I want it to fire an event when i change the status of that custom post type from 'pending' to 'booked'.

The event should send a confirmation email to the user in question.

I tried the following :

```
function show_alert_msg( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( 'Booked' === $new_status && 'pending' !== $old_status && $post->post_type=='Booking' )
        
     {
         echo '<script>alert(Show message after transition to booked)</script>' ;
    }else{
        echo '<script>alert(failed)</script>' ;

    }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'show_alert_msg', 10, 3 );
```

but whenever i change the status nothing happens.

what i am doing wrong? and how can I approach this correctly so that when the booking status changes from pending to Booked, the confirmation email is sent to the user ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because there are several bugs in your code!

- You're using `WP travel plugin`. This plugin register its custom post type as `"itinerary-booking"`, but in your code, you're checking for a custom post type called `"Booking"` which doesn't exist, so that condition never returns true!

  > You could navigate to this path:
  > *"your website folder > wp-content > plugins > wp-travel > inc"*
  > and open up `class-post-types.php` file on line `126` you see this `register_post_type( 'itinerary-booking', $args );`
- Also, you're using `transition_post_status` action hook which is used for the checking a post status. The status of `pending` and `booked` are custom post meta data and saved into the database under the `wp_travel_booking_status` name and have nothing to do with the post status itself! Which means it's totally different than what you're trying to do.

[image] [image]

So, this filter hook `transition_post_status` is not responsible to pick up those statuses.

- Also, when trying to debug/test your code, specially on `transition_post_status` and `save_post` hooks, do **NOT** use javascript `alert`, `console.log` and/or php `echo`, `print_r`, `var_dump` etc. because when you hit those hooks, printing, echoing, alerting won't work. Just use php `die` function which will stop the app and lets you know that you hit the hook.
- Also capitalization matters! Make sure you're using the right capitalization for your values, for example, in this case, everything is lowercase. So keep an eye on that!

---

Now what can you do about it?

1. Well, you could change your hook to `save_post` action hook which means every time that you update your post, it'll fire!
2. You could change your conditional check to look for `itinerary-booking` custom post type.
3. Also you could use `get_post_meta` function, to check for your status change!

Now putting it all together, you could use the following code:

```php
add_action( 'save_post', 'sending_email_confirmation_to_user');

function sending_email_confirmation_to_user( $post_id )
{

  if ( 'itinerary-booking' == get_post_type( $post_id ) ){

    $post_status_after_update = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'wp_travel_booking_status', true );

    if( 'booked' === $post_status_after_update ){
      die("Send your email here!");
    } else {
      die("your post status is not booked!");
    }
  }

}
```

**Note:**

- I used `die` statement just to give you an example, so make sure to replace `die("Send your email here!");` with your custom function that sends out emails!
- Status of `booked` is lowercase, so don't change it to uppercase like the one you tried in your code! Otherwise it won't work!
- When your post status is not "booked", you don't have to do anything, i used `die("your post status is not booked!");` just to give you an example!

---

##### Update

When you use `save_post` hook, it runs every time you update your custom post data, **BUT** you do NOT want to send an email every single time. Right?

When you change the status from 'pending' to 'booked' you could `save a meta data` in the database so that you know you've already sent an email  confirmation and you don't want to send another email. You could do that using `update_post_meta` function.

```php
add_action( 'save_post', 'sending_email_confirmation_to_user');

function sending_email_confirmation_to_user( $post_id )
{

  if ( 'itinerary-booking' == get_post_type( $post_id ) ){

    $post_email_status = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_confirmation_email', true );
    $post_status_after_update = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'wp_travel_booking_status', true );

    if( 'booked' === $post_status_after_update && empty( $post_email_status )){
      $email_sent = update_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_confirmation_email', 'sent-at-'. date( 'M_d_Y-H_i_s' ) );
      die("Send your email here!");
    } 
  }

}
```

**Note:**

- This will make sure that you only send your email confirmation once!
- If the email confirmation data is empty in the database, it'll send the email and update the value in the database and won't send extra emails.
- Also, I've stored a meta data in your database called `custom_confirmation_email` and used `'sent-at-'. date('M_d_Y-H_i_s')` as its value which looks like this: `sent-at-Oct_01_2021-17_42_42` which is the date and time when the status changed from 'pending' to 'booked' for the first time.

---

**All of the snippets and explanations have been fully tested and work!**

Comment: Thanks a lot, that explained too many questions i had.

Comment: I tried the solution you suggested but the hook 'save_post' didnt fire the function, tried other hooks but only one triggered the function.it was the 'update_post_meta' but the problem is that it was passing one argument and it was not the post Id it was some other integer.
note: I am writing this code in functions.php

Comment: When you say *"save_post didn't fire the function"*, how do you know? Because I had tested the code before i sent it to you. When you change the status from "pending" to "booked" you see `die("Send your email here!");` Right? If you see it, it means you're hitting the right hook. If you want to test it, don't use javascript alert! You won't see it on the screen. Just use `die("Send your email here!");`.

Comment: I installed that plugin just to solve your problem, and I tested the code. If you can't get it to work then, you must have a bug somewhere else. The code I sent you, is working fine.

Comment: I am sorry you are right I made a mistake by using alert instead of the die function for testing, but it does work fine now the only problem i have is that it fires everytime i update a custom post which has a 'Booked' status and I want it to only get triggered when I change it from Pending to Booked . thanks again for the help